# Nested Promises executed in the "wrong" order

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm trying to open 2 files in a+ mode and then try to read their content and send it back to the user. I had it implemented using nested callbacks but I wanted to try doing it with Promises, thus I wrote the following:

```
var chain1 = [];  
var c1Promise1 = new Promise(func(res,rej){  
   fs.open('path','a+',func(err,fd){  
     if(err)  
       {rej(err)}  
     else  
       {res(fd)}  
     })  
chain1.push(c1Promise1)  
//Same thing for the second promise, just different path  
Promise.all(chain1).then(fds=>{
    var chain2 = []  
    var c2Promise1 = new Promise(func(res,rej){  
       fs.readFile(fds[0],'utf-8',func(err,data){
          console.log("data1 = " + data)  
          if(err){  
            rej(err)
          }  
          else{  
            res(data)  
          }  
       })  
})
chain2.push(c2Promise1)
//Same thing for c2Promise2 but different fd (fds[1]) and .log("data2 = " + data)
Promise.all(chain2).then(data=>{
       console.log("data3 and 4 = " + data[0] + ' ' + data[1])
   },err=>next(err))
},err=>next(err))  

On console i get:  
"data3 and 4" = undefined undefined    
"data1 = " actual data in the file  
"data2 = " actual data in the file.
```

Am I missing something?Isn't this supposed to behave like, data1, data2 and only then data 3 and 4!? Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

promises are for asynchronity. therefore starting multiple promises one after another doesn't mean they are executed/they finish in order.

if my understanding's right your code does basically the following (psuedo-js-code):

```
var chain1 = [c1promise1, c2promise2];
Promise.all(chain1).then( // wait for execution
    var chain2 = [c2promise1, c2promise2];
);
Promise.all(chain2).then( // at this point in time the execution of chain1 doesn't have to be finished!
    // do sth
);
```

if you want the chains executed in order (! the promises IN the chain still don't have to be executed in order) you should chain the promises:

```
var chain1 = [c1promise1, c2promise2];
Promise.all(chain1).then( // wait for execution
    return [c2promise1, c2promise2];
).all(chain2).then(
    // do sth
);
```

or even better: use async/await as proposed by Nico

Comment: no they were supposed to be nested!Promise.all(chain2) is created and executed inside Promise.all(chain1) thus order is guardanteed. BUT im such a tard i miss-closed parenthesis!At least in my code, fixed it now. Sorry for wasting time

Answer (score 1):

`Promise.all()` return right away is does not wait for promise to be done.
So in your case, everything below the first `Promise.all` should be in a `.then()` block.

By the way, this kind of code is very hard to read. You can try to use `fs = require('mz/fs')` that handle promise directly. And maybe use async/await.

Something like:

 `let fs = require('ms/fs');
 let data1 = await fs.readFile(path1, 'utf8');
 let data2 = await fs.readFile(path2, 'utf8');`